# Instantiate lua classes using Luabind

Tags: c++, lua, luabind

Is it possible to instantiate Lua "classes" using Luabind from a c++ application? To illustrate the problem, consider the following simple Lua script:

```
class "Person"

function Person:__init(name)
    self.name = name
end

function Person:display()
    print(self.name)
end
```

I can instantiate this class in the same Lua script and everything works fine. However, I want to instantiate a new object from this class using Luabind from within my c++ application. I have tried the following:

```
luabind::object myObject = luabind::globals(L)["Person"]("John Doe");
myObject["display"]();
```

I would expect to see "John Doe" output to the console. Instead, I am greeted with a Lua runtime error. The call to create the new object seemingly works. The problem appears to be that `self`, in the display function, is nil.

Comment: You need to find out how luabind expects you to call a method as opposed to a normal function and/or manually pass the object to the display method in that call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*self* is *nil* because if you use the ":"-operator in lua, then lua will automatically provide the caller as first argument.
so:

```
somePerson:display() == somePerson.display(somePerson)
```

Therefore you need to provide that self-argument too:

```
luabind::object myObject = luabind::globals(L)["Person"]("John Doe");
myObject["display"](myObject);
```

Or even better: Use the simple functions in luabind available for that purpose

```
luabind::object myObject = luabind::globals(L)["Person"]("John Doe");
luabind::call_member<void>(myObject, "display");
```